# Create a new array from the elements that are unique for several arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, google-maps

Here is a piece of my code:

```
            var things = new Object();
            things.location = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < clickedMarkers.length; i++) {
                var mark = clickedMarkers[i],
                    markLatitude =  mark.position.lat(),
                    markLongitude =  mark.position.lng();

                things.location.push({
                    'lat': markLatitude,
                    'lng': markLongitude
                });
            }
```

as a result we have the following pairs:

```
{lat:53.5412,lng:9.994180000000028},{lat:53.0862838,lng:8.789075099999991},   {lat:53.0738902,lng:8.805211800000052},{lat:53.5412,lng:9.994180000000028},{lat:53.5412,lng:9.994180000000028}
```

I compare the element of each pair by 'lat', using the following code:

```
            var arr = {};

            for ( var j=0, len=things.location.length; j < len; j++ )
                arr[things.location[j]['lat']] = things.location[j];

            things.location = new Array();

            for ( var key in arr )
                things.location.push(arr[key]);
```

But the correct way is to compare that both elements of the pair lat and lng are differ, because for the big array of pairs - lat can be the same, but lng - differ.

How to compare both elements of each pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on geocodezip's answer. Used the following code:

```
  //get all markers for the cluster;
  var clickedMarkers = cluster.getMarkers();

  //get the base point to compare all other markers
  var base = new google.maps.LatLng(clickedMarkers[0].position.lat(), clickedMarkers[0].position.lng());

            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < clickedMarkers.length; i++) {
                var mark = clickedMarkers[i],
                    markLatitude =  mark.position.lat(),
                    markLongitude =  mark.position.lng();
                var _coordinates =  new google.maps.LatLng(markLatitude,   markLongitude);

                var point = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(_coordinates, base);
                total= total + point;
            }

            console.log('total', total);

            if (total == 0)
           {some action}
```

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. use the [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) `.equals` method
2. use the [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) method, if the distance is less than some small number (say 1.0 meters), treat them as the same (latitudes and longitudes are floating point numbers, comparing them for equality is problematic).